# All object become "enable selection" with hotkey

Tags: selection-tools

I hope someone understands. I have more than 10000 objects and in my scene. None of them are named properly (and please don't suggest me to). Some of them are locked(unselectable), I don't want to find them in outliner one by one to unlock, I just want to do is be able to Unlock (make selectable) them all directly with one click hotkey, how to do it?

I know it can shift+click collection arrow icon in outliner to unlock collection objects, but I need to click all collection one by one, I needs to click 100 times if I have 100 collection.

What I need is very simple, Press the keyboard once with hotkey, all scene objects Unlock (make selectable), no mouse click, no selection, that's it. how?

This problem has bothered me for many years, and I can't find a solution. I often have to deal with it at work. 3dsmax and other 3D software have this function, but I can't find it in Blender.

Comment: AFAIK there is no "one click" solution - but i might be wrong (i am still learning as well), but it should be pretty easy with a script.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot toggle the _Selectable_ button for multiple objects with one click. You can filter the _Outliner_ to just show unselectable objects, you then can select them all in the _Outliner_, but you cannot toggle the button for all of them at once.